# Webgl not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, rendering, webgl, html-rendering

I created webgl objects. Localy my scene is rendering and I can see the 3 objects, rotate them, use the functionalities.
When I commit the code on github: https://kotodorova.github.io/ea5.html
I see a black space, where my canvas should be and there are no error messages.

I have tried resizing the canvas but it did not change anything.

Comment: works for me on chrome on linux

Comment: Yah! Working for me too on Windows 10 Edge, Chrome and Firefox, what browser/system  are you running into the problem on??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.